# Sorting a Map with dates as the key (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, sorting

I want to sort a Map in javascript.
The map looks like this:

```
0: { key: '2020-09-29', value: { foo: 1, bar: 2} },
1: { key: '2020-09-01', value: { foo: 3, bar: 4} },
2: { key: '2020-09-08', value: { foo: 5, bar: 6} }
```

and so on..

I can't find a solution for this, can someone give me a hint?

I already tried something like this:

```
days_map = new Map([...days_map].sort(function(key, value) { return new Date(key); }));
```

but it's not sorting the map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = [{
    key: '2020-09-29',
    value: {
      foo: 1,
      bar: 2
    }
  },
  {
    key: '2020-09-01',
    value: {
      foo: 3,
      bar: 4
    }
  },
  {
    key: '2020-09-08',
    value: {
      foo: 5,
      bar: 6
    }
  }
]

input.sort((a, b) => {
  const first = a.key
  const second = b.key
  
  return first > second ? 1 : (first < second ? -1 : 0)
});
console.log(input);
```

Comment: This is not handling equality between dates and it can lead to potentially wrong results in some corner cases.

Comment: if his input key value is the date format rather than empty, i guess there is nothing wrong. @VLAZ

Comment: There is no handling for  `a === b`. Comparators have to return *three* values - for greater, lesser, and equal. You're omitting the last possibility and lumping it into "lesser". Thus your comparator is not symmetrical - it producing different results for `compare(a, b)` and `compare(b, a)`. This can trick the sorting algorithm into sorting some items as unequal when they aren't. Moreover, this will be dependant on environment and dataset, so *extremely* hard to find and debug under normal circumstances. Sorting and date sorting are both well documented, no reason to deviate.

Comment: Also relevant is that there is no need to convert to `Date` objects. The dates are ISO 8601 strings, which means that lexicographical sorting is equal to chronological sorting for them.

Comment: i got your point, thanks for suggestion. i just updated answer

Comment: I did "Array.from(days_map)" and sorted it like you. The output was something like:
['2020-09-30', '2020-09-28', ... , '2020-09-13', '2020-09-1', ... '2020-09-12']...
weired?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the array with the key with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
let map = new Map([['2020-09-29', { foo: 1, bar: 2 }], ['2020-09-01', { foo: 3, bar: 4 }], ['2020-09-08', { foo: 5, bar: 6 }]]),
    sorted = new Map(Array.from(map).sort(([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)));

console.log([...map]);
console.log([...sorted]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```